# Is there any methodto bulk upload achievements to Steamworks?

Tags: achievements, steamworks

I'm developing a game with approximately 100 achievements, creating and maintaining them all through the Steamworks WebGUI would be very time-consuming.
Epic has a bulk uploader for achievements (https://dev.epicgames.com/docs/services/en-US/GameServices/BulkImporterExporterTool/index.html)

Does anyone know if there are some similar method for Steam Achievements?